# how do you update a devise user via API calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I've used HTML forms in the past to update devise users, but now I have a Rails 4 application with devise for authentication and I'd like to be able to control my users from remote using RestClient/CURL. I was surprised to look at the devise user routes and notice that there's no /users/:id route (no GET and especially no PUT).

I would like to be able to issue a command such as this:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-X PUT http://localhost:3000/users/18232 \
-d '{ "user": { "email": "updated_email@gmail.com", "currrent_password": "password" }}' \
-u admin@gmail.com:password
```

If I don't provide the user ID in the URL path, then this request will be successful, but it will update the admin's email - which is not what I want. If there's a different way to specify the user that I need updated (providing the id inside the data hash will not work), then that would be great... even though that would break RESTful routes standards for devise.

Comment: How about creating your own Controller + Logic

Comment: Shouldn't you add "resources :users" in your application routes.rb for /users/:id to work?

Comment: I guess I'll need to write my own if I can't find any existing solutions. And, I guess I could add "resources :users" into routes, but what is the "devise" way of doing things? In this case, the routes will go to another controller, or I would have to override the devise registrations controller. I skimmed through the code and I don't understand everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can build your own actions in the devise controller

use this to generate the controllers for the users

```
rails generate devise:controllers users
```

the controllers will be created in `app/controllers/users/`

then you can add your own action to the controller

for example:

```
def update_info
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update(user_params)
    puts 'the user info successfully updated' #add whatever you want
  else
    puts 'failed'
  end
end
```

after that, you need to create a route for the action in the `routes.rb`

```
devise_scope :user do
  put 'users/:id', to: 'users/sessions#update_info'
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about this option, so I had created my own users controller. Even though it does the job, I prefer doing it the official way.